# Location Manager error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using location manager

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_kCLDistanceFilterNone", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added corelocation.framework into frameworks folder of my project, the project is success on cleaning but failed and give the same three errors on building

Comment: have you added import statement in your class?

Comment: yes i did : #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Comment: Try removing the framework from your bundle by deleting it (not just releasing a reference to is) from your project then add it back in; clean->clean all-> run

Comment: I would like to give +10 to you man. thats it :) :) :)

Comment: Just Cleaning worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import Framework Which you have already done also add the following to your .h file where you are using the CLLocation class such as

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface UntitledViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager*      locationManager;
    CLLocation*             locationObject;
}

@end
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: you are missing the delegate CLLocationManagerDelegate :) and i did the same still in problem :(

Comment: I wanted to highlight that you need to add #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation,h> I have added the delegate as well..and It builds without errors.

Comment: ok thanks man, that was obviousely a good guess, but i am done with the problem in some other way :)

Comment: I'm working on an ionic (cordova) project and the cli forgot to add the CoreLocation framework so I added it myself in `Link Binary With Libraries`

Answer (score 2):

Removing and adding the framework back, is the correct solution.
Thank for the answer, it saved me a lot work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your class

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Comment: Can you check if the corelocation.framework is added inside the Frameworks folder?

Comment: Just out of curiosity how did you add the core location framework?

Comment: right click on any of your existing framework in Framework folder and then select Show in Folder, after this a simple drag and drop, anyway i am done with the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in my unit test project.

Problem was that I added CoreLocation.framework to my project but forget to add in unit test project.